# pandas how to normalize 3 different datatypes in one column to required format

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

HOW TO NORMALIZE ALL VALUES (EXCEL TIME SERIES, STRING, DATETIME) TO ONE STRIGN FORMAT YYYY Q (2018 Q1)?

```
   Date                Name
0  NaN                 DD
1  2018-12-01 00:00:00 FF
2  2018-06-01 00:00:00 EE
3  43252               FF
4  43435               GG
```

I have the above DataFrame df and when I call dtype on a specific column it displays:

```
dtype('O')
```

When I loop through elements:

```
for x in df['Dates'].unique():
    print(type(x))
```

Out [ ]:

```
<class 'float'>
<class 'datetime.datetime'>
<class 'datetime.datetime'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'datetime.datetime'>
<class 'str'>
```

so i tried to create a function:

```
def normalize(x):
    if type(x)==datetime.datetime:
        x = pd.Period(x,freq='y').astype(str) + ' Q' + pd.Period(x,freq='q').astype(str)
    else:
        pass
```

and called it when creating a column:

```
df['Quarters'] = data['Dates'].apply(lambda x: nomralize(x))
```

but when I check the column dtypes it says none = no values.

Can you please point me to the right direction?

The sample values I have in the column:

[image]
What I'm trying to achieve is to normalize all values to YYYY Qx apart from those already in this format.

I tried Dataframe.dt, parse dates as datetime object, the issue is always that there is more than one type. I even tried subsetting using DataFrame.select_dtypes() but this doesn't work neither. Any help please?

Below solution did not work for me as raises Unknown String Format error, full code:

```
import xlrd, pandas as pd, numpy as np

f = r'C:\Users\G01024822\Desktop\datestest.xlsx'

df = pd.read_excel(f,parse_dates=True,na_values='')

def calculate_date(x):
    if isinstance(x, (int, str)):
        d = xlrd.xldate.xldate_as_datetime(x, 0) if isinstance(x, int) else x
        d = pd.to_datetime(d, errors='raise')
        return str(d.year) + ' Q' + str(d.quarter)
    else:
        return np.nan

#df['Normalised'] = df['Date'].map(lambda x: calculate_date(x))
#df['Normalised'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: calculate_date(x))
#df['Normalised'] = df['Date'].apply(calculate_date)
```

All commented lines throw the same error

Comment: What do you mean by normalize? And how should a `NaN` or the number `43252` be converted to YYYY Q?